# js optimization for classList.Add

Tags: javascript, performance

I'm trying to squeeze as much performance out of my js as possible.  I need to make sure an element has a class assigned.  Is it faster to check and only assign if it's not there, or always assign even if it's already there?

In other words, which is faster

```
if (!element.classList.contains('class')) element.classList.add('class');
```

or always do this

```
element.classList.add('class');
```

The class is already there about 10% of the time.

Comment: That's a "question" for https://jsperf.com

Comment: What's with the down vote?  Because I didn't know about jsperf.com?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone suggested using jsperf.com.  Here is the sample https://jsperf.com/classlist-add-vs-classlist-contains/1

Looks like checking first is about 5% faster than just adding

Comment: _"Looks like"_ is not an answer... Especially not when the "answer"/results cannot be reproduced. With my setup Firefox is more than 400 times faster (1.4b to 3m Ops/sec).

Comment: If you go to the jsperf test I linked to and run it you can get your own result.  Mine was 4.87% faster which is close enough to 5%.  "Looks like" is a common phrase used in English to mean "approximately".

Comment: Where do you think that those numbers are coming from? o.O And thanks, but I understand the English language good enough for this...

Answer (score 0):

The *element.classList.add* checks if class is already there anyway. Try to add same class twice, it will not be added. I am positive that the Browser is by far quicker than js to check if should add. So, go ahead and add without checking.